# Python Pandas: Merge or Filter DataFrame by Another. Is there a Better Way?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

One situation I sometimes encounter is, I have two dataframes (`df1`, `df2`) and I want to create a new dataframe (`df3`) based on the intersection of multiple columns between `df1` and `df2`.

For example, I want to create `df3` by filtering `df1` by columns `Campaign` and `Group`.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Campaign':['Campaign 1', 'Campaign 2', 'Campaign 3', 'Campaign 3', 'Campaign 4'], 'Group':['Some group', 'Arbitrary Group', 'Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Done Group'], 'Metric':[245,91,292,373,32]}, columns=['Campaign', 'Group', 'Metric'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Campaign':['Campaign 3', 'Campaign 3'], 'Group':['Group 1', 'Group 2'], 'Metric':[23, 456]}, columns=['Campaign', 'Group', 'Metric'])
```

`df1`

```
     Campaign            Group  Metric
0  Campaign 1       Some group     245
1  Campaign 2  Arbitrary Group      91
2  Campaign 3          Group 1     292
3  Campaign 3          Group 2     373
4  Campaign 4       Done Group      32
```

`df2`

```
     Campaign    Group  Metric
0  Campaign 3  Group 1      23
1  Campaign 3  Group 2     456
```

**I know I can do this with merge**...

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on=['Campaign', 'Group'], suffixes=('','_del'))
#df3
     Campaign    Group  Metric  Metric_del
0  Campaign 3  Group 1     292          23
1  Campaign 3  Group 2     373         456
```

but then I have to figure out how to `drop` columns that end with `_del`.  I guess this:

```
df3.select(lambda x: not re.search('_del', x), axis=1)
##The result I'm going for but required merge, then select (2-steps)
     Campaign    Group  Metric
0  Campaign 3  Group 1     292
1  Campaign 3  Group 2     373
```

**Questions**

What I'm mainly interested in is returning `df1` that's simply filtered on `df2`'s `Campaign|Group` values.

1. Is there a **better** way to return `df1` without resorting to `merge`?
2. Is there a way to `merge` but NOT return `df2`'s columns to the `merge` and returning only `df1`'s columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your `df1` and `df2` have exactly the same columns. You can first set those join-key columns as index and use `df1.reindex(df2.index)` and a further `.dropna()` to produce the intersection.

```
df3 = df1.set_index(['Campaign', 'Group'])
df4 = df2.set_index(['Campaign', 'Group'])
# reindex first and dropna will produce the intersection
df3.reindex(df4.index).dropna(how='all').reset_index()

     Campaign    Group  Metric
0  Campaign 3  Group 1     292
1  Campaign 3  Group 2     373
```

### Edit:

Use `.isin` when key is not unique.

```
# create some duplicated keys and values
df3 = df3.append(df3)
df4 = df4.append(df4)

# isin
df3[df3.index.isin(df4.index)].reset_index()

     Campaign    Group  Metric
0  Campaign 3  Group 1     292
1  Campaign 3  Group 2     373
2  Campaign 3  Group 1     292
3  Campaign 3  Group 2     373
```

Comment: In example data above, this works great but when I apply this concept to my real datasets, I get `Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`.  I verified that `df1` and `df2` have the exact same columns. Any ideas of the cause and how to fix?

Comment: @Jarad Can you try using the `.isin` to act as the filter rule, for example `df3[df3.index.isin(df4.index)].reset_index()`.

Comment: That did the trick.  Really appreciate your help Jianxun Li.  This concept seems like a great alternative approach to `merge`.

Comment: @Jarad You are most welcome. Glad that it helped. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `groupby` and `filter` as follows:

```py
# Compute the set of values you're interested in.
# In your example, this will be {('Campaign 3', 'Group 1'), ('Campaign 3', 'Group 2')}
interesting_groups = set(df2[['Campaign', 'Group']].apply(tuple, axis=1))
# Filter df1, keeping only values in that set
result = df1.groupby(['Campaign', 'Group']).filter(
    lambda x: x.name in interesting_groups
)
```

See the [`filter` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) for another example.