# Pandas: Update Multiple Dataframe Columns Using Duplicate Rows From Another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge, lookup

I have two dataframes: `df1` and `df2`.  **If** the `Display Name` from `df2` is in `df1`'s `Display Name` column, I want to assign `df1`s `Type`, `Format`, `Behavior`, `Datatype` values to `df2`s values.

I've tried `merge` every way I could think of. I think `loc` is my best hope but I can't seem to get the assignment syntax right.  Also, I'm looking for a succinct answer - preferably a one-liner.

Something like this:

```
df2.loc[df2['Display Name'].isin(df1['Display Name']), /
        ['Type', 'Format', 'Behavior', 'Datatype']] = ???
```

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
  {'Behavior': ['Attribute', 'Attribute', 'Attribute', 'Attribute', 'Attribute',
              'Attribute', 'Attribute', 'Metric', 'Metric', 'Metric', 'Metric',
              'Metric', 'Metric', 'Metric', 'Metric'],
   'Datatype': ['object', 'object', 'object', 'object', 'object', 'object',
              'object', 'int64', 'int64', 'int64', 'int64', 'float64',
              'float64', 'float64', 'float64'],
   'Display Name': ['Campaign', 'Campaign ID', 'Campaign ID', 'Campaign state',
                  'Campaign state', 'Currency', 'Currency', 'Impressions',
                  'Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Clicks', 'CTR', 'CTR', 'Avg. CPC',
                  'Avg. CPC'],
   'Format': ['{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{:,.0f}', '{:,.0f}',
            '{:,.0f}', '{:,.0f}', '{:.2f}%', '{:.2f}%', '${:,.2f}', '${:,.2f}'],
   'Type': ['String', 'String', 'String', 'String', 'String', 'String', 'String',
          'Integer', 'Integer', 'Integer', 'Integer', 'Percent', 'Percent',
          'Currency', 'Currency']},
  columns=['Display Name', 'Type', 'Format', 'Behavior', 'Datatype'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
  { 'Behavior': [ 'Attribute', 'Metric', 'Metric', 'Metric', 'Attribute',
                'Metric', 'Metric', 'Attribute', 'Metric', 'Metric', 'Metric'],
  'Datatype': [ 'object', 'float64', 'float64', 'float64', 'object', 'int64',
                'int64', 'object', 'float64', 'float64', 'float64'],
  'Display Name': [ 'Match type', 'Destination URL', 'Final URL',
                    'Mobile final URL', 'Labels', 'Impressions', 'Clicks',
                    'CTR', 'Avg. CPC', 'Cost', 'Avg. position'],
  'Format': [ '{}', '{:.2f}', '{:.2f}', '{:.2f}', '{}', '{:,.0f}', '{:,.0f}',
              '{}', '{:.2f}', '{:.2f}', '{:.2f}'],
  'Type': [ 'String', 'Float', 'Float', 'Float', 'String', 'Integer',
            'Integer', 'String', 'Float', 'Float', 'Float']},
  columns=['Display Name', 'Type', 'Format', 'Behavior', 'Datatype'])

df2_vals_in_df1 = df2.loc[df2['Display Name'].isin(df1['Display Name']), df2.columns[:]]
df1_vals_in_df2 = df1.loc[df1['Display Name'].isin(df2['Display Name']), df1.columns[:]]
```

What it looks like:

```
>>> df1
      Display Name      Type    Format   Behavior Datatype
0         Campaign    String        {}  Attribute   object
1      Campaign ID    String        {}  Attribute   object
2      Campaign ID    String        {}  Attribute   object
3   Campaign state    String        {}  Attribute   object
4   Campaign state    String        {}  Attribute   object
5         Currency    String        {}  Attribute   object
6         Currency    String        {}  Attribute   object
7      Impressions   Integer   {:,.0f}     Metric    int64
8      Impressions   Integer   {:,.0f}     Metric    int64
9           Clicks   Integer   {:,.0f}     Metric    int64
10          Clicks   Integer   {:,.0f}     Metric    int64
11             CTR   Percent   {:.2f}%     Metric  float64
12             CTR   Percent   {:.2f}%     Metric  float64
13        Avg. CPC  Currency  ${:,.2f}     Metric  float64
14        Avg. CPC  Currency  ${:,.2f}     Metric  float64

>>> df2
        Display Name     Type   Format   Behavior Datatype
0         Match type   String       {}  Attribute   object
1    Destination URL    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
2          Final URL    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
3   Mobile final URL    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
4             Labels   String       {}  Attribute   object
5        Impressions  Integer  {:,.0f}     Metric    int64
6             Clicks  Integer  {:,.0f}     Metric    int64
7                CTR   String       {}  Attribute   object
8           Avg. CPC    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
9               Cost    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
10     Avg. position    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64

>>> df2_vals_in_df1
  Display Name     Type   Format   Behavior Datatype
5  Impressions  Integer  {:,.0f}     Metric    int64
6       Clicks  Integer  {:,.0f}     Metric    int64
7          CTR   String       {}  Attribute   object
8     Avg. CPC    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64

>>> df1_vals_in_df2
   Display Name      Type    Format Behavior Datatype
7   Impressions   Integer   {:,.0f}   Metric    int64
8   Impressions   Integer   {:,.0f}   Metric    int64
9        Clicks   Integer   {:,.0f}   Metric    int64
10       Clicks   Integer   {:,.0f}   Metric    int64
11          CTR   Percent   {:.2f}%   Metric  float64
12          CTR   Percent   {:.2f}%   Metric  float64
13     Avg. CPC  Currency  ${:,.2f}   Metric  float64
14     Avg. CPC  Currency  ${:,.2f}   Metric  float64
```

Note how `df1_vals_in_df2` `Display Name` might have the same name multiple times.  Their `Type`, `Format`, `Behavior`, `Datatype` values will always be the same values in both rows.

**Expected Output of `df2`**:

```
>>> df2
        Display Name     Type   Format   Behavior Datatype
0         Match type   String       {}  Attribute   object
1    Destination URL    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
2          Final URL    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
3   Mobile final URL    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
4             Labels   String       {}  Attribute   object
5        Impressions  Integer  {:,.0f}     Metric    int64 <-- same
6             Clicks  Integer  {:,.0f}     Metric    int64 <-- same
7                CTR  Percent  {:.2f}%     Metric  float64 <-- changed
8           Avg. CPC Currency ${:,.2f}     Metric  float64 <-- changed
9               Cost    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
10     Avg. position    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
```

**Takeaway #1**: rows 5, 6 are the same because they are the same in both `df1` and `df2`.

**Takeaway #2**: row 7, changed from `String, {}, Attribute, object` to `Percent, {:.2f}%, Metric, float64` - the row values from `df1` because `Display Name` from `df2` was found in `Display Name` in `df1`.

**Takeaway #3**: row 8, changed for the same reasons noted in takeaway #2.

Tried:

Q1:[Python Pandas: Merge or Filter DataFrame by Another. Is there a Better Way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925572/python-pandas-merge-or-filter-dataframe-by-another-is-there-a-better-way)

Doesn't address this question because I'm not trying to create a new dataframe; I'm trying to replace values in an existing dataframe from another.

Q2:[Replace column values based on another dataframe python pandas - better way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768657/replace-column-values-based-on-another-dataframe-python-pandas-better-way)

Doesn't address this question because that example contains one df with correct values whereas my situation is a df with correct and incorrect values.

Apologies that this is such a long question. I just wanted to provide enough context.

Comment: Well, you could make this much easier to read by shrinking df1 and df2 substantially.  5 rows and 2 columns would get the point across just as easily.  All that said, are you just looking for `combine_first()`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It probably was TMI (too much info).  I did find a solution with your suggestion `combine_first()` which I'll post. However, I'm not in love with it because because it appends rows which then require deduplication.  Second, in order to get the expected output above, I need to do a wizardy custom mapping (gotta be an easier way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `combine_first` will be an elegant solution, as per JohnE, provided you set `Display Name` as an index. This brings me to another point. I think that your task is well-defined only if 'Display Name' corresponds to exactly one set of attributes within each table. Assuming that, you can drop duplicates, set index and use `.update` like so:

```
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()

df1 = df1.set_index('Display Name')
df2 = df2.set_index('Display Name')

df2_c = df2.copy()

df2.update(df1)
df1.update(df2_c)

del df2_c
```

You can reset the dimensions of `df1` with an auxiliary index if you like.

Comment: In the documentation for [update()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), it say 'Aligns on indices'.  Is that why you set the index to be 'Display Name'?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Accepting this answer as correct.  However, this answer is very similar to my Q1 I referenced above.  And, nobody else (except myself) provided an answer.  So... best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal but I was able to recreate my expected output.  Problem is, I wanted to avoid making `df3` and want to do the replacement all within `df2` so this isn't ideal.

`df2` before:

```
        Display Name     Type   Format   Behavior Datatype
0         Match type   String       {}  Attribute   object
1    Destination URL    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
2          Final URL    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
3   Mobile final URL    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
4             Labels   String       {}  Attribute   object
5        Impressions  Integer  {:,.0f}     Metric    int64
6             Clicks  Integer  {:,.0f}     Metric    int64
7                CTR   String       {}  Attribute   object
8           Avg. CPC    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
9               Cost    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
10     Avg. position    Float   {:.2f}     Metric  float64
```

`df3` after:

```
df3 = df2.combine_first(df1).drop_duplicates('Display Name', keep='last')
df3 = df3.set_index(df3['Display Name'].map(dict(zip(df2['Display Name'], df2.index)))).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

        Display Name      Type    Format   Behavior Datatype
0         Match type    String        {}  Attribute   object
1    Destination URL     Float    {:.2f}     Metric  float64
2          Final URL     Float    {:.2f}     Metric  float64
3   Mobile final URL     Float    {:.2f}     Metric  float64
4             Labels    String        {}  Attribute   object
5        Impressions   Integer   {:,.0f}     Metric    int64
6             Clicks   Integer   {:,.0f}     Metric    int64
7                CTR   Percent   {:.2f}%     Metric  float64
8           Avg. CPC  Currency  ${:,.2f}     Metric  float64
9               Cost     Float    {:.2f}     Metric  float64
10     Avg. position     Float    {:.2f}     Metric  float64
```

`df2` before and after comparison:

```
   Display Name   Type Format Behavior Datatype
0          True   True   True     True     True
1          True   True   True     True     True
2          True   True   True     True     True
3          True   True   True     True     True
4          True   True   True     True     True
5          True   True   True     True     True
6          True   True   True     True     True
7          True  False  False    False    False
8          True  False  False     True     True
9          True   True   True     True     True
10         True   True   True     True     True
```